# Remove specific version of package from custom apt repository

Tags: apt, package-management, reprepro

I was searching for a solution to delete a specific version of a package from a repository with `reprepro`. I could only find:

```
sudo reprepro remove focal foobar
```

which seems to delete the complete package with all versions. I would like to keep the older versions.

Also a good enough solution would be to force to regenerate new checksums and replace the package when running `sudo reprepro includedeb focal ~/debian_repo/*.deb`, but I have not found a switch here to ignore this kind of error.

Comment: What is reprepro? Have you tried to read its official documentation?

Comment: Sure, I read it. reprepro is the basic fundamental command for managing repositories. I expect it is known by anyone knowing an answer for this problem.